# Android notifyDataSetChanged() not working on Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

How should I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` here?

`EditOrDeleteDevicesAdapter adapter = new EditOrDeleteDevicesAdapter(this, paths);
 list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Here `paths`(contains data) is an `ArrayList` which is being passed into the adapter (a separate file) and then rendered into the list. In the adapter file, I am changing the data in the database and in the `paths` ArrayList. However, I don't know how to update the `list.setAdapter(adapter)` simultaneously using `notifyDataSetChanged()`!

P.S.: The data updates once I go back and re-render the activity.

Comment: I believe that you wouldn't use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` there (which appears to creating the original adapter), rather you would likely use it immediately after (or very soon after) refreshing/changing **paths** wherever that is done. I personally do it in the `onResume` method if another activity is invoked that changes the underlying data or within the appropriate code (e.g.for a button click where the `onClick listener` calls a method within the activity, then I do it within the method).

Comment: post whole your code and we can find out your problem